# Does the ISO files produced by Windows Media Creation Tool depend on the specific OS?

Tags: windows, iso-image

I ran Windows Media Creation Tool in a Windows 10 installtion. It took a lot of time to create an ISO file. Is the ISO file is specific to the Windows Installation on which the Media Tool is run? or, can I use the ISO file to upgrade a Windows 7 on another laptop?

Do the applicable license agreements allow this?

Comment: You mean with regards to 32-bit or 64-bit if you picked the "both" option then it doesn't matter, all that matters, is the version of Windows 10 you downloaded..

Answer (score 0):

As Ramhound has metioned above, you need to pay attention to the version of the Windows 10. Here is the [Upgrade Path](http://winsupersite.com/windows-10/windows-10-upgrade-paths) for Windows 10.

> Do the applicable license agreements allow this?

No, the license is applied when you install the Windows 10. There is no licensing related information in the ISO. If you already have the license for Windows 7, then it should be fine to upgrade to Windows 10. Please backup your important data before the upgrade.